Poly Time Algorithm for (0/1) Basic Feasible Solution
I have an LPP where the basic feasible solution is a vector in $\{0,1 \}^n$. I am not very well versed in linear programming and would like to know if poly-time algorithms exist to find such a basic feasible solution. The most well-known methods I could find on Wikipedia solve general basic feasible solutions but are not worst-case polytime. Any help would be appreciated!
Edit 1: I am adding more context. The LPP I am solving is of the form optimise any linear objective function, for example, say just the constant 1 given $Ax < b$ and $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. I am interested how to find (0/1) basic feasible solutions in such a scenario.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming

Relax your ILP, round off, and you will get a basic feasible solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I believe you are interested in problems of the form $\min_x c^\top x$ subject to $Ax \le b$ and $x\in \{0,1\}^n$. This problem is known to be NP-hard. This means, there is strong evidence to believe that these problems do not have any polynomial-time algorithms to solve them exactly. A phrasing you will find in many textbooks and even papers is, "Unless P=NP, there is no polynomial-time algorithm that can solve the above problem" and it is widely believed (without proof) that P $\neq$ NP.
Ideas like rounding off the solution after solving the (much easier) linear program: $\min_x c^\top x$ subject to $Ax \le b$ (without including $x\in \{0,1\}^n$), may give you something that may or may not even satisfy all the constraints!

I updated the question to give more context? Is the problem still NP-hard?

Yes. It is still NP hard
